# Is it possible to fake a Linux machine's uptime?

Tags: linux, uptime

I would like to set an old Linux server's uptime output, so that it continues to count from my set timepoint, rather than its actual last reboot. Is that possible? Can I somehow edit the timestamp from when the machine last booted?

Comment: It might be possible to fake the data in the uptime command.  However, anyone looking to disprove that can just look in the logs.

Comment: If you have a 32bit kernel, you can say the [jiffies counter rolled over](https://lkml.org/lkml/2002/2/18/13) (funny discussion) and fake n times 497 days with n any natural number... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at that: http://www.etheus.net/UptimeFaker.

**But be warned**. It may **break** your system. Your system can become **unstable**!